# Deletion of a question with upvoted answers

Tags: support, deletion

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/414036/rationals-and-irrationals-on-the-real-number-line/ is not very well-posed, but all the answers seemed to interpret it the same way: prove that for every two irrationals $i_1 < i_2$, there is a rational $i_1 < r < i_2$.  It attracted three different answers, all upvoted.

The question itself has been downvoted and closed, and now I see that it has two votes to delete.  If it were deleted, the answers would be lost, which I think would be unfortunate.  What can be done to prevent this?

Comment: It looks like it's probably a duplicate of something.  If you can find another question for me to merge it into, this will preserve the answers while scrapping the question.

Comment: It's an exact duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/421580/is-there-a-rational-number-between-any-two-irrationals

Comment: @MJD Or of http://math.stackexchange.com/q/226793/ which already has answers.

Comment: I will cheerfully leave the decision to the moderators.

Comment: In the process I found two dyadic versions of this problem, and flagged http://math.stackexchange.com/q/84565/ as duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/q/23039/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Fair enough, I merged it with [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/421580/12952) question, which I believe is more succinctly worded and therefore better for preventing future duplicates, despite being a spiritual duplicate of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/226793/12952) question.

Comment: Thanks very much.